# RegEx finds match correctly but returns it incorrectly

Tags: javascript, html, regex

JavaScript:

```
var docHeadText = document.head.innerHTML;
var patt =/\/*:.+?:*\//g;
patt.compile(patt);
docHeadText.match(patt);
```

HTML:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function JValues(){
alert('/*:hello-world:*/');
}
</script>
</head>
```

It returns `:hello-world:*/` but I want it to return `/*:hello-world:*/`

Comment: `*` is a special character in regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
var patt =/\/\*:.+?:\*\//g;
```